# How do I find what version of WSUS I have installed on Windows Server 2012?

Tags: windows-server-2012, powershell, wsus

I'm trying to automate WSUS with powershell, however to do this I need to know what version is installed. How do I find this information?

The server is using Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code to get the version of WSUS in PowerShell:

```
[void][reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration")
$wsus = [Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.AdminProxy]::getUpdateServer(“dc1”,$False)
$wsus.Version
```

Comment: I can seem to get this to work on Server 2016.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use PowerShell:

```
get-itemproperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Update Services\Server\Setup\' -Name IISPreviousInstallRevision
```

Answer (score 0):

WSUS was initially a separate software which you had to download and install, but since Windows Server 2008 R2 it has been included in the OS.

Windows Server 2012 R2 runs WSUS 4.0.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_Update_Services